# Azure user principal name inconsistency

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

We have an app that reads users from Azure AD and allows them to login.
It works perfectly for internal users but for guests there's an inconsistency.

1. Requesting a user data from Microsoft Graph will get me UserPrincipalName as `sample_sample.com#EXT#@organization.onmicrosoft.com`. And this is exactly what I see in Azure Portal and I suppose this one is correct.
2. During OAuth from identity token I will get (in `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name`) `live.com#sample@sample.com`

Why are they different? Is there a way to get them the same or somehow associate them?

Comment: What authority are you using when signing in the user in your app? I.e. are you using the "common" v2.0 endpoint or are you using a tenant-specific endpoint?

Comment: We use tenant-specific endpoint. Original external user email is @gmail.com

Comment: This is a bit confusing behaviour :\ Is there a particular reason you want to use the UPN to match the user? A better id would be the objectId of the user / oid claim.

Comment: I could have used them yes. But everything was ok until I found this issue with externals and my customers already have upn in config. I have a very simple config and upn is a kind of self-describing thing. Otherwise I would need to provide additional user name in the ui.